# Why is my entire document rotated by 90 without \begin{landscape}

Tags: landscape, lscape

Why my entire document was rotated by 90 degrees when I used `\usepackage{lscape}`, even though without `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}`

```
\documentclass{aastex63}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\centering
my text
\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccccc}
\caption{my title}
\endfirsthead
\caption{countinue}
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
my table
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I compiled my document with PDFTeXify

Comment: Don't use lscape with this class. It is doing lot of special stuff which clashes with lscape.

Comment: Presumably you added `lscape` because you wanted to rotate the `longtable`. If so, you might want to take a look as the `deluxetable` environment that comes with `aastex`: "There is support in the AASTeX package for tables via two mechanisms: LATEX’s standard table environment, and the deluxetable environment, which allows for the formatting of lengthy tabular material. Tables may be marked up using either mechanism, although use of deluxetable is preferred." According to the [user guide](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/), `deluxetable` also offers pagebreaks and rotation.

Comment: @leandriis Your comment is very helpful.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Yes, that's the problem, thank u.